# How to get the process id in msbuild target

Tags: msbuild

How can I get the proc-id of the msbuild process inside a target? I want to read it and write it out?

Alternatively, does MSBuild has some kind of session id that we can capture?

I want to run a T4 task only once per build run and thinking of a conditional way to build it. Otherwise it runs multiple times

```
<TransformOnBuild>false</TransformOnBuild>
<TransformOnBuild Condition="'$(SomeCondition)' == 'true'">false</TransformOnBuild>
```

Comment: please rephrase your question (basically your last paragraph is the q, the rest is a possible solution you were thinking of that probably won't work anyway) and add some more info: what do you mean with 'once per build'? Are you building a solution with multiple projects and you want to run the task once? Or are you using a custom build file? Or is it something else? Is the target defined in every project now? Or why does it run multiple times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to run something once you can wrap it in a target, MSBuild does not execute same target twice no matter how many times it was called. If you want a simple mutex you can use the usual lock file technique using built-in `WriteLinesToFile` and `Delete` tasks with `InitialTargets`. If you want actual process id, i.e. the MSBuild node (of many) that is executing your task, you can write an inline task, see example below.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="Process" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyName="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <Id ParameterType="System.Int32" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Code>Id = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;</Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="Foo">
    <Process>
      <Output PropertyName="Id" TaskParameter="Id" />
    </Process>
    <Message Text="Process $(Id)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```